# Shiro 'Unable to instantiate class'

Tags: java, shiro

This is my problem:
I have a web application that worked well until Saturday. But then it can not load my entitlements anymore.
Here is the piece of code in my `shiro.ini` file

```
entityRealm =  com.cagecfi.shiro.EntityRealm 
securityManager.authorizer = $entityRealm
authentif = com.cagecfi.Entities.Utilisateur
```

and the java class :

```
public class EntityRealm extends AuthorizingRealm{

    protected UtilisateurFacadeLocal utifl;
    protected ProfilRoleFacadeLocal prfl;
    protected static Utilisateur utilisateur;
    protected static Profil profil;
    protected static List<ProfilRole> profilRoles;

    public EntityRealm() throws NamingException {
        System.out.println("enter entity realm");
        this.setName("entityRealm");
        CredentialsMatcher credentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher("SHA-256");
        this.setCredentialsMatcher(credentialsMatcher);
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        this.utifl = (UtilisateurFacadeLocal) context.lookup("java:global/DOLEANCESAPPLI/UtilisateurFacade");
        this.prfl = (ProfilRoleFacadeLocal) context.lookup("java:global/DOLEANCESAPPLI/ProfilRoleFacade");
        System.out.println("out entity realm");
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken) throws AuthenticationException {

        final UsernamePasswordToken token = (UsernamePasswordToken) authcToken;

        utilisateur = utifl.getOneBy("login", token.getUsername());

        SimpleAuthenticationInfo simpleAuthenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo();
        try {
            if (utilisateur != null) {
                simpleAuthenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(utilisateur.getLogin(), utilisateur.getPassword(), getName());
            } else {
                simpleAuthenticationInfo = null;
                throw new UnknownAccountException("Utilisateur inconnu");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return simpleAuthenticationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        String userId = (String) principals.fromRealm(this.getName()).iterator().next();
        utilisateur = utifl.getOneBy("login", userId);
        if (utilisateur != null) {
            final SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
            profilRoles = this.prfl.getBy("profil", utilisateur.getProfil());

            final List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            profilRoles.stream().forEach((proRole) -> {
                roles.add(proRole.getRole().getNom());
            });
            info.addRoles(roles);

            return info;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static Utilisateur getUser() {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            return utilisateur;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Subject getSubject() {
        return SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    }

    @Override
    public void clearCachedAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        super.clearCachedAuthorizationInfo(principals);
    }

}
```

n a bizarre way, `shiro` has been sending me this since Saturday.

```
Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class [com.cagecfi.shiro.EntityRealm] for object named 'entityRealm'.  Please ensure you've specified the fully qualified class name correctly.
```

To clarify just after a clean and build it began to send me this error.
I even recovered the previous backup of the project and still nothing.
Can someone help me and tell me where I missed something?
Thank you.

Comment: So have you checked that the `com.cagecfi.shiro.EntityRealm` has been deployed to the correct place?  Are there other (earlier) exceptions in the log file that might explain this?  Can you show us the *complete* stacktrace, including any nested exceptions?

Comment: Do you have a time machine?  Or a copy of your application in version control from when it was working?

Comment: actually i looked into the `glassfish` server but nothing. But nevertheless where could I find that and also how can i paste te complete stacktrace, 
going to the fact that the number of comments characters is limited. How can i check if the `com.cagecfi.shiro.EntityRealm` has been deployed to the correct  place. Thanks

Comment: 1) You edit the question! 2) By looking in the correct place on your deployment platform! (I'm not sure where it would be because I'm not familiar with Glassfish, but the Glassfish documentation should tell you.)

Comment: So, i found the mistake on my application. I change the names of my Beans and anyhow the application start to don't recognize them. So i was oblige to create a new project with the new Beans name. And since it works perfectly.